# Rank of free abelian group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I was reading Munkres Section 67 when I got stuck on this proof of Theorem 67.8, which could be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989922/can-g-2g-and-mathbb-z-2-mathbb-z-times-times-mathbb-z-2-mathbb-z). Especially, I don't understand why arguing that $G/2G$ has cardinality $2^n$ is helpful... I feel I'm not getting the motivation even at the first line of the proof. Hopefully someone can help to clarify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_n$ denote the free Abelian group with $n$ generators. The theorem is that if $m\ne n$ then $F_n\not\cong F_m$. Equivalently $F_m\cong F_n$ implies $m=n$.

Right then, $F_m\cong F_n$ implies $F_m/2F_m\cong F_n/2F_n$ which implies
$|F_m/2F_m|=|F_n/2F_n|$ which implies $2^m=2^n$ which implies $m=n$.

Comment: But then why in the first line Munkres abruptly claims that Fn=Cartesian product of n copies of Z? Isn’t that alone enough to arrive at your claimed alternative statement of the theorem? I’m still confused.

Comment: @Macrophage They are showing that the products are different. You don't know a priori that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is different from $\mathbb{Z}^3$. There are groups where $A \times A \cong A$ for example

Comment: @PaulPlummer I think it makes more sense now...

Comment: @PaulPlummer uh but in fact Z^m is not isomorphic you Z^n for n not equal to m right? Is it just that Munkres don’t want to resort to this fact but rather wants to compare cardinality of quotient group as you suggested.

Comment: @macrophage Munkres is proving they are not isomorphic/ranks is well defined! If you want to take it as a fact that is fair be but at some point someone has to prove it. Maybe you have a different proof in mind...

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you can distinguish cardinalities $2^n$ while $\mathbb{Z}^n$ all have the same cardinality (and the association with $2^n$ is canonically determined by the rank). If $G/2G$ and $G'/2G'$ have different cardinalities then $G$ and $G'$ were not isomorphic

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there are groups where $A \times A \cong A$

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the theorem states that $n$ is uniquely determined by $G$. Now, if you know that $|G/2G| = 2^n$, it suffices to uniquely determine $n$.